# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'

Tags: python3, aws, django

When I try to collect all of my static files in my project in one location with `python manage.py collectstatic`, I get the error

**`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters`**

`django_filters` is in my Installed Apps settings.

Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/ubuntu/Episode-One/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/ubuntu/Episode-One/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/ubuntu/Episode-One/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 
24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/ubuntu/Episode-One/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", 
line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/ubuntu/Episode-One/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 
90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'
```

Comment: You need to install `django-filter` : `pip install django-filter`.

Comment: that worked! Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `django-filter` (please note without `s`):

```
pip install django-filter
```